# need some help for creating a working search function

Tags: python, database, tkinter, search

This is my very first post in stackoverflow.

I am a pilot who is a newbie to the software world, trying to learn python myself.

I am trying a create a simple search function with a gui to search multiple values in a list.

I've created 2 input boxes for pilots' name and rank.

I've also created a class called Pilot with 2 adjacent lists of 2 random pilots' info.

My purpose is to search through the lists to return all relevant info about the pilot when I fill the name and rank boxes, but I've came to a stop. I also tried to connect "name" and "rank" for searching function but that failed, as well.

It gives the following error:

> ALWAYS THE RESULT IS "NOT FOUND"

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class Pilot():

  def __init__(self, name, age, rank, fleet, callsign, fail):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.rank = rank
    self.fleet = fleet
    self.callsign = callsign
    self.fail = fail





  def __repr__ (self):

      return "({},{},{},{}, {}, {})".format(self.name, self.age,self.rank,self.fleet, self.callsign, self.fail)
    


p1= Pilot("tom kazansky","22","lt","f14", "iceman","0")
p2= Pilot("pete mitchell","23","lt","f14", "maverick","3")
pilots =[p1,p2]



label_1 = Label(root, text = "name")
label_2 = Label(root, text = "rank")
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root)

def p_name(pilots):
    return pilots.name
def p_rank(pilots):
    return pilots.rank


def search(*pilots, key1 = p_name, key2 = p_rank):
            
    if entry_1 and entry_2 in pilots:
        print("found!")
            
    elif entry_1 and entry_2 not in pilots:
        print("not found!")
        
        

button_1 =Button(root, text = "search", command = search)


label_1.grid(row =0)
label_2.grid(row =1)

entry_1.grid (row =0,column =1)
entry_2.grid (row =1,column =1)

button_1.grid(row =3)



    
root.mainloop()
```

What prevents the search from returning records? Maybe something about *args or ** kwargs ?

Comment: Your `search` method has one expected argument to it, `pilots`. From what I can tell, you want that to be pre-populated as you're checking membership with your conditionals inside that method. You either need to update your button to pass something in to the `pilots` argument of `search`, or assign a default value to `pilots` in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You seem pretty close. We'd probably need to know what sort of errors your getting or what exactly isn't working before being able to help too much.

I can tell you that you haven't actually gotten the text from inside the Entry GUI objects:

```
 entry_1 = Entry(root)

 if entry_1 and entry_2 and entry_3 in pilots:
```

According to your above code `entry_1` is the text object itself (the box on the page). The `if` statement checks if all of these text box objects are in your list of pilot objects (which I assume to be false).

If you're trying to get the contents of those text boxes on pressing the search button then you need to use `Entry.get()`

If I'm understanding your intentions properly, then you should start with updating the following function

```
def search(pilots, key1 = p_name, key2 = p_rank):
        
if entry_1.get() and entry_2.get() in pilots:
    print("found!")
        
elif entry_1.get() and entry_2.get() not in pilots:
    print("not found!")
```

You can find out more about Tkinter using this link for general usage:

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter

And this link for more specific information

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

Best of luck!

Comment: thanks a lot! I tried your update but it still keeps giving return `self.func(*args)
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pilots'  `

Comment: Looks like @gallen already answered that in a comment to your original post. You're missing the 'pilots' argument when you call your search function. It's slightly more complicated to add function arg when using `Button.command`. You'll have to wrap the function call to add an arg, or add a default arg to your function declaration.

I think wrapping the function call is the easiest and looks like this:

button_1 = Button( root, text = "search", command = lambda: search(pilots) )

The `lamda` command acts as a simple function with no args that calls your search function w/ args